# Unable to change the value of input type=color inside an ngFor on Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I've got a really strange behavior with the code below in angular ^14.2.0. I can't change the input value of the color picker in the first form but it's perfectly working in the second. All others fields in the first form working as well.

app.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent {
  notWorkingForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup<any>({});
  workingForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup<any>({});
  fieldsDescription: IndicatorEditForm = {
    fields: [
      {
        name: 'period',
        label: 'Period',
        type: 'number',
        value: 20,
      },
      {
        name: 'stdDev',
        label: 'Std. Dev.',
        type: 'number',
        value: 2,
      },
      {
        name: 'color',
        label: 'Color',
        type: 'color',
        value: '#ff0000',
      }
      ]
  }

  foo: Foo = new Foo();

  constructor() {
    this.foo.toForm().fields.forEach(field => {
      this.notWorkingForm.addControl(field.name, new FormControl(field.value));
    });

    this.fieldsDescription.fields.forEach(field => {
      this.workingForm.addControl(field.name, new FormControl(field.value));
    });

    this.workingForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log('working', value);
    });

    this.notWorkingForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log('not working', value);
    });
  }
}

class Foo {
  toForm(): IndicatorEditForm {
    return {
      fields: [
        {
          name: 'period',
          label: 'Period',
          type: 'number',
          value: 14,
        },
        {

          name: 'stdDev',
          label: 'Std. Dev.',
          type: 'number',
          value: 2,
        },
        {
          name: 'color',
          label: 'Color',
          type: 'color',
          value: '#cccccc',
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}

export type IndicatorEditForm = {
  fields: IndicatorEditFormField[];
}

export type IndicatorEditFormField = {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  type: IndicatorEditFormFieldType;
  value: any;
  options?: IndicatorEditFormFieldOption[];
}

export type IndicatorEditFormFieldType = 'text' | 'select' | 'number' | 'color';
export type IndicatorEditFormFieldOption = {
  label: string;
  value: any;
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<h2>Not working</h2>
<form [formGroup]="notWorkingForm" class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let field of foo.toForm().fields">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text">{{field.label}}</span>
          <input [type]="field.type" [formControlName]="field.name">
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<h2>Working</h2>
<form [formGroup]="workingForm" class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let field of fieldsDescription.fields">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <span class="input-group-text">{{field.label}}</span>
          <input [type]="field.type" [formControlName]="field.name">
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

It's working if I only switch the right side of ngFor to "fieldsDescription.fields" and leave as is the form's initialization. I can't figure out why ? What did I miss ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figure out why the first form isn't working. It's something I didn't know about how Typescript (and I think more globally javascript) working with prototype. It's because the variable foo know the instance of Foo's class and this instance says it has 2 properties, constructor and toForm(). But never ask what theses properties contains! It's only when we do foo.toForm() that we'll ask to know what's inside the method, before that it's like if the toForm() method return an empty array, because the prototype knows that it must return an array of something but that all.

And now come Angular with change detection and dom refreshing, when ngFor is executing the first time the prototype is only an empty array but right after toForm() method load and expose it's content so the ngFor restart to loop through the array and load input.

When I'm editing input, Angular detect changes inside theses inputs and refresh the dom, it fire another cycle for the ngFor with the behavior I explain before, emptying the content and recreating inputs. Refreshing the form before it has the time to updating the new value into its variable.

Btw, inputs period and stdDev of the first form not working great too, I can only set one number with keyboard before loosing focus but I didn't notice it before...

So to overcome this problem, I just need to set a new variable with the content of toForm() and using this variable for the right side of ngFor, like that the content of toForm() is already loaded and ngFor no longer sees a prototype with an empty array.